# Compile typescript without transpiling async functions

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await, ecmascript-2017

Is there a way to use the TypeScript compiler only to remove type annotations, but not transpiling async functions? Something like a `{ target: 'esInfinite' }` option? The reason is: There are browsers that already support async functions, so I wish to have a build target where those functions are not affected.

example input:

```
async function foo(a : number) : Promise<void> {}
```

example output:

```
async function foo(a) {}
```

Comment: There's a [pull request](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/11407) to add support for ES2017, but until that lands, not as far as I am aware.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In your `tsconfig.json`, change your target to `ES2017`, then it will preserve the `async/await`.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    .....
    "target": "ES2017",
    .....
  }
}
```

DO make sure your **run-time** supports it natively!!!

PS: as of `Apr 2018`, *AWS Lambda* now supports Nodejs 8. You should be able to use the above config for it.

Answer (score 0):

This feature was already requested [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5361). Targeting es2016 and es2017 should be available in the [Community](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/milestone/2) milestone and in [TypeScript 2.1](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/milestone/20).

Comment: We are now at TypeScript 4.3 and setting "target" to "es2017" will preserve async / await statements using "target" with "es2016" will output a polyfill using `var __awaiter`.